# SASS version mismatch between system and grunt-contrib-compass?

Tags: sass, gruntjs, yeoman, compass-sass, grunt-contrib-compass

I've encountered the following issue with grunt-contrib-sass/compass:

(https://github.com/nex3/sass/issues/746)

Compiling this:

```
.badge {

    border: 1px solid black;

    &-info {
        background:blue;
    }
}
```

Errors this:

```
Sass Error: Invalid CSS after " &": expected "{", was "-info {"
"-info" may only be used at the beginning of a compound selector.
```

I have the latest SASS version (3.3.7) installed on the system (Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS), and running `scss` from the command line on a fresh file with above code DO work.

However creating a fresh project with `yo webapp` (Yeoman generator-webapp), with Grunt, gives the above error.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Right, so this is probably it, however in a different context. It's well worth mentioning because folks using Yeoman might not be familiar with everything under the hood.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @cimmanon kindly commented, this is probably due to version conflict between SASS and Compass.

As Compass uses it's own version of SASS and I was using grunt-contrib-compass (and not SASS), and my version of Compass was < 1 - the effect was that the 3.3 version I had on my system wasn't used.

Watch out for that when using out-of-the-box Yeoman generators.

Answer (score -1):

So when compiling this with 3.3.6 of SASS I get:

```
.badge {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.badge-info {
  background: blue;
}
```

But with 3.2.19 I get the same error you do:

```
Invalid CSS after "    &": expected "{", was "-info {"

"-info" may only be used at the beginning of a compound selector.
```

There's a rather involved history to using suffixes this way, see: [A Change in Plans for Sass 3.3](http://blog.sass-lang.com/posts/184092-a-change-in-plans-for-sass-33)

So you have a SASS version problem somewhere in your toolchain.

Comment: Yes this is what I suspect, but I can't find the specific spot where this version mismatch occurs. It's probably buried somewhere in the Yeoman stack. I've already invested a day's work in this...